# fields and exclude in tastypie

Tags: tastypie

I would like to include some fields in a GET response and include a smaller subset of fields in a POST confirmation response. I am having to have a lot of del bundle['field1'], del bundle['field2'] in alter_detail_data_to_serialize to achieve this. Is there any generic way I can specify fields and excludes per request type in my resource?

Answer (score 5):

I have looked through Tastypie source and my conclusion is as follows....

You could try to instrument your resource and change the value of `excludes` attribute on the fly when the method is POST, but this will be tricky and most importantly hackish.

Therefore I guess your best bet is to do what you're doing, but perhaps instead of doing multiple `del bundle[ 'field' ]` introduce a `post_excludes` attribute or some such and implement a nicer and more flexible way of getting rid of those fields. You could for example do something like this:

```
class YourResource( Resource ):

    class Meta:
        # ...
        post_excludes = [ 'foo', 'bar' ]
        # ...

    # ...

    def alter_detail_data_to_serialize( self, request, data ):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            data.data = { 
                key : value for key, value in data.data.copy().iteritems() if \
                key not in self._meta.post_excludes }
        return data

    # ...
```

This would be cleaner and would comply with Tastypie's "rules" which is important in order to not end up with tangled, hacked code which is hard to maintain.

Hope this helps :)